# Devise - forgot password not showing error message if the email does not exist in the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When a users clicks forgot password, it takes them to the forgot password page with a field for them to input their email address. If their email address is in the database, everything is peachy, but if the email address does NOT exist in the database, it just redirects to the same page, but does not show an error message.

How can I get the error message to appear?

/view/devise/passwords/new.html.erb

```
...
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
    <h1>Reset Password</h1>     

    <div class="login-fields">

        <p>Instructions on resetting your password will be emailed to you.</p>

        <%= render :partial => '/shared/messages' %>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email', :class => 'login username-field' %>
        </div> <!-- /field -->

    </div> <!-- /login-fields -->

    <div class="login-actions">

        <%= content_tag(:button, :type=>:submit, :class => "button btn btn-secondary btn-large") do %>
            Send me reset password instructions
        <% end %>

    </div> <!-- .actions -->

    <div class="login-social">
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div>

<% end %>
...
```

/views/shared/_messages.html.erb

```
<% if alert || flash[:alert] || flash[:error] %>
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>
        <h4 class="alert-heading">Error!</h4>
        <%= alert %>
        <%= flash[:error] %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<% if flash[:success] || notice || flash[:notice]%>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>
        <h4 class="alert-heading">Success!</h4>
        <%= flash[:success] %>
        <%= notice %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is any of the HTML being rendered? I.e. does it show the "Error!" heading but not the actual message? Or is it just showing nothing at all?

Comment: Be aware that this is exposing information to potential attackers. Someone trying to guess valid email addresses in your system would be able to tell if someone had an account or not based on whether they got an error message or not. It's similar to the info revealed if [your login form says whether the username or password was incorrect](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1076787&seqNum=6). You'll need to balance security against usability for your particular application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your shared messages partial you are only displaying errors from the controllers. You need to include errors that are attached to your model. In this case the error message is attached to the User model. You /views/shared/_messages.html.erb should actually look like:

```
<% if alert || flash[:alert] || flash[:error] %>
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>
      <h4 class="alert-heading">Error!</h4>
      <%= alert %>
      <%= flash[:error] %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% if model.errors.any? %>
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>
      <h4 class="alert-heading">Error!</h4>
      <ul>
        <% model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li>* <%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% if flash[:success] || notice || flash[:notice]%>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>
      <h4 class="alert-heading">Success!</h4>
      <%= flash[:success] %>
      <%= notice %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

and while rendering the partial, you need to pass in the model.

```
<%= render '/shared/messages', model: resource %>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I actually have another partial that I use for model errors, but didn't realize that I was missing it here.

Comment: Thanks. This answer was helpful, but in my case, I had to check that resource was actually defined. Instead of `<% if model.errors.any? %>` and `<%= render '/shared/messages', model: resource %>`, I simply checked for `resource` in my partial, e.g. `<% resource.errors.full_messages.each.each do |message| %>` and made no changes to `render`, i.e. `<%= render '/shared/messages' %>`

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the default `passwords/new.html.erb` view that comes with devise, you'll see that it includes a call to

`<%= devise_error_messages! %>`

You can use that same helper in your view, if you like, to render the error messages attached to the user object (as was pointed out in Anurag's answer, the messages are attached to the model object rather than in the flash).

This helper will return markup that looks like:

```
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>1 error prohibited this user from being saved</h2>
  <ul><li>email not found</li></ul>
</div>
```

if you want to customize this, you can do so easily. Just don't use the helper, and instead add your own custom markup that accesses `resource.errors.full_messages` to get the "email not found" message. Or honestly since that's the only error you're going to get on this page, you could just do:

```
<% unless resource.errors.empty? %>
  <div>email not found</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form is calling the `create` method at the `password_path`.  Make sure that the `create.html.erb` displays a flash message on error as well as success, if any exists.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't show in the frontend that an email doesn't exist in the database. That can be used to exploit your application. A hacker can set a script to check which accounts are in the database and then try to exploit them.